# Increasing image quality in a wordcloud+matplotlib image

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I have a wordcloud created in Python with WordCloud and Matplotlib packages, but I can't download a High quality image of it.
If I zoom a bit, I can not understand any of the small words. I would like to be able to understand all the words if I zooz, if not I would like to remove them.

How can I increase this image quality? I tried to do It increasing dpi, increasing the original image's size and changing the image type to pdf. I think the low quality comes from my wordcloud and not from Matplotlib.

This is my image:
[image]

And this is what I find if I zoom a bit:
[image]

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter


df=pd.read_csv('word_freq_counter.csv')

word_freq_counter = Counter(dict(zip(df['Item'], df['Count'])))


mask = np.array(Image.open('fnatic_2.png'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

wc = WordCloud(

    relative_scaling=0.3,
    repeat=True,
    colormap='Oranges',
    font_path='C:/Windows/Fonts/seguiemj.ttf',
    mask=mask, background_color="grey",
    max_words=2000, max_font_size=256,
    min_font_size=3,
    random_state=42, width=mask.shape[1],
    height=mask.shape[0])
wc.generate_from_frequencies(word_freq_counter)

plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")


fig.set_facecolor('gray')

ax.set_title('Fnatic\'s last week in Twitter', fontdict={'fontsize': 15},
             loc='left', pad=20, color='black')

plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("result.png",dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the figure size -> `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))` to increase the figure size to help increase resolution/quality?

Comment: @Redox, you solved my problem! Amazing! I've been dealing with this for hours! You canna post it as an answer instead as a comment so I can recognize you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no option to directly increase resolution, you can increase the figure size at initialization to increase the size of the plot. This should give you better quality pic as the size of the file will increase...

Use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
```

to increase the figure size to a large number (20 in this case) and check the quality of the picture.